# Central/middle letter of a string.(methods)

Tags: c#

I need to solve the following question which i can't get to work by myself(newbie^^)..:

Ok, the question: Create a method which will print the central letter of a string (given as a parameter). I need to use the property lenght to determine the lenght.

So for example the string: Books. the middle/central letter is o.
 Hope its a bit clear..

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know how to determine the lenght of the string. Now the problem is to divide the word and then write down the next letter or something.

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. What have you tried so far? Show us some code and we can help.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: How should it handle even-length strings?  E.g. what would the central letter of "letter" be?

Comment: @arootbeer: +1 for re-usability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tips:
1. Type string has a `Length` property.
2 .If you know the index of the character you want, you can ask for it using: `myString[index]`.
3. Knowing what to do with string that has even number of characters is necessary to answer that question.
4. Consider integer devision.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
string middleLetter(string arg)
{
   return arg[arg.Length >> 1];
}
```

Comment: 1. This is a homework question - just putting code here does not help. 2. This is not C#. 3. What happens when the word has an even number of characters? Should be specified more explicitly. 4. Why the shifting? To confuse a newbie?

Comment: @Kirk: why is this clever? It is useless micro optimization which results in more unreadable code ...

Comment: Sorry, it was not C# indeed. Why shifting? Because I hate to divide by 2 when division helps ^_^ What happens when length is even? >> 1 divides by 2 rounded down.

Comment: @tanascius, you understand that something can be simultaneously clever and unreadable, right?  I'd even go so far as to suggest they often go hand in hand. :)

Comment: @Kirk, I do ... but a '/2' will probably end up like a '>>1' - as the same IL code ... in this case, there is no cleverness ... and *Jay* even stated that he is a newbie ...

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static string FindMiddleChar(string s)
    {
        int middleChar = s.Length / 2;

        if (s.Length > 2)
        {
            if (s.Length % 3 == 0)
            {
                if (s.Length <= 3)
                {
                    return s[middleChar].ToString();
                }
                return s[middleChar - 1] + s[middleChar].ToString();
            }
            else if (s.Length % 3 != 0)
            {
                if (s.Length <= 4)
                {
                    return s[middleChar - 1] + s[middleChar].ToString();
                }
                return s[middleChar].ToString();
            }
        }
        return "Error, the input string must contain at least three characters.";
    }
```